# How to play youtube video by given link in web app like Whatsapp using youtube api in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I am creating a web app like Facebook. Now, with the feature of pictures & videos, I like to add **youtube api** in my web app. Via this youtube api my users can share the link of youtube video's & by the link they will see the videos in youtube like **WhatsApp**. I am using **Node.js(express), mongoose**. Please, help how to start with that.

Comment: Have you made any attempts yet?

Comment: I was seeing the document part of youtube api. In addition I am using the https package for youtube api calling. Now, I was doing this in code->  https.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos",function(res){

});                                                                                                                                         Now, in documents section I have saw the parameter part for api's that's why I am confusing about the parameter part with code.      Please, help

Comment: Please take some time to edit the question with context and your attempts.